# Is there better way to just get an Json element from circe

Tags: scala, circe

I am a new user of circe api, currently I use following code to get an element from the JSON document:

```
((json.getOrElse(Json.Null) \\ name head) asString) get
```

It look using more code then it should be, if there better suggestion?

Comment: If you can use play-json, I'd recommend it. Not an answer, obviously, but it's much more widely used as far as I can tell.

Comment: Would you mind adding some details to the question? Such as, what's the type of `json`? Furthermore an excerpt of the JSON you want to navigate would be useful too.